# Аналог messageBox в AWT

Tags: messagebox, awt, java

Подскажите метод в AWT, аналогичный MessageBox() из других языков. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane`. [Аналог MessageBox в Java](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/java/443879.all)
Там даже тема на форуме названа как у Вас ^_^

ну коль так принципиально, хоть и не понятно зачем именно awt, при условии его "тяжести"

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class DialogExample {
        private static Dialog d;
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Frame window = new Frame();
            d = new Dialog(window, "Alert", true);
            d.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
            Button ok = new Button ("OK");
            ok.addActionListener ( new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                {
                    // Hide dialog
                    DialogExample.d.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            d.add( new Label ("Click OK to continue"));
            d.add( ok );

            d.setVisible(true);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Замечательно, но это класс Swing, увы.

Comment: в коммент не влезло, отписал в ответ